# How to make iterations over dates in R

Tags: r, as.date

This is a more general problem I get in R. Say I want to create a subset for a dataset `data` that contains the first 10 days the days 1,...,10. For a single day I can easy make the subset like this

```
data_new <- subset(data, data$time == as.Date(as.character(2016-01-01)) )
```

But say I want the first 10 days in January 2016. I try to make a loop like this

```
data_new <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=1)
for(j in 1:10) {
    data_new[,j]= subset(data, data$time==as.Date(as.character(2016-01-j)))
}
```

but this code can not run in R because of the term `as.character(2016-01-j)`.

How can I create such a subset?

Comment: You mean `as.character(paste("2016-01-",ifelse(j<10,"0",""),j,sep=""))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
data_new = subset(data, data$time %in% as.Date(paste0("2016-01-", 1:10)))
```